# TypeError Cannot pickle _thread.luck object error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-synapse

I am using pyspark in synapse to create a data frame and adding computed column using user defined function. If there is any issue in the function I need to log that information. However I am getting error TypeError Cannot pickle _thread.luck object error when logger.error is used in except block of the function.

part of my code look like

```
logger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger("com.test.test")
   def log_test(arg):
 try:
    return 1/arg
 except Exception as e:
    logger.error("Divided by zero error occurred")

udf_log_test = udf(lambda col:log_test(col) if col != 0 else 0, IntegerType())
    
    df = df.withColumn('TestColumn', udf_log_test(lit(0)))
```

Error Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 527, in dumps
        return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, pickle_protocol)
      File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 73, in dumps
        cp.dump(obj)
      File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 602, in dump
        return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
    TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
    PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py:527, in CloudPickleSerializer.dumps(self, obj)
    526 try:
--> 527     return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, pickle_protocol)
    528 except pickle.PickleError:

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py:73, in dumps(obj, protocol, buffer_callback)
     70 cp = CloudPickler(
     71     file, protocol=protocol, buffer_callback=buffer_callback
     72 )
---> 73 cp.dump(obj)
     74 return file.getvalue()

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py:602, in CloudPickler.dump(self, obj)
    601 try:
--> 602     return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
    603 except RuntimeError as e:

TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-109665656057519>:1
----> 1 df = df.withColumn('TestColumn', udf_log_test(lit(0)))

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py:322, in UserDefinedFunction._wrapped.<locals>.wrapper(*args)
    320 @functools.wraps(self.func, assigned=assignments)
    321 def wrapper(*args: "ColumnOrName") -> Column:
--> 322     return self(*args)

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py:299, in UserDefinedFunction.__call__(self, *cols)
    297         sc.profiler_collector.add_profiler(id, memory_profiler)
    298 else:
--> 299     judf = self._judf
    300     jPythonUDF = judf.apply(_to_seq(sc, cols, _to_java_column))
    301 return Column(jPythonUDF)

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py:219, in UserDefinedFunction._judf(self)
    212 @property
    213 def _judf(self) -> JavaObject:
    214     # It is possible that concurrent access, to newly created UDF,
    215     # will initialize multiple UserDefinedPythonFunctions.
    216     # This is unlikely, doesn't affect correctness,
    217     # and should have a minimal performance impact.
    218     if self._judf_placeholder is None:
--> 219         self._judf_placeholder = self._create_judf(self.func)
    220     return self._judf_placeholder

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py:228, in UserDefinedFunction._create_judf(self, func)
    225 spark = SparkSession._getActiveSessionOrCreate()
    226 sc = spark.sparkContext
--> 228 wrapped_func = _wrap_function(sc, func, self.returnType)
    229 jdt = spark._jsparkSession.parseDataType(self.returnType.json())
    230 assert sc._jvm is not None

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py:51, in _wrap_function(sc, func, returnType)
     47 def _wrap_function(
     48     sc: SparkContext, func: Callable[..., Any], returnType: "DataTypeOrString"
     49 ) -> JavaObject:
     50     command = (func, returnType)
---> 51     pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
     52     assert sc._jvm is not None
     53     return sc._jvm.SimplePythonFunction(
     54         bytearray(pickled_command),
     55         env,
   (...)
     60         sc._javaAccumulator,
     61     )

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py:5248, in _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
   5245 def _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc: "SparkContext", command: Any) -> Tuple[bytes, Any, Any, Any]:
   5246     # the serialized command will be compressed by broadcast
   5247     ser = CloudPickleSerializer()
-> 5248     pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
   5249     assert sc._jvm is not None
   5250     if len(pickled_command) > sc._jvm.PythonUtils.getBroadcastThreshold(sc._jsc):  # Default 1M
   5251         # The broadcast will have same life cycle as created PythonRDD

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py:537, in CloudPickleSerializer.dumps(self, obj)
    535     msg = "Could not serialize object: %s: %s" % (e.__class__.__name__, emsg)
    536 print_exec(sys.stderr)
--> 537 raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)

PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
```

Comment: Please share the full traceback.

Comment: Yes share the full error traceback.

Comment: Not all objects can be pickled. Clearly, _thread.RLock is one such object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the udf automatically tries to serialize the function and sends it to worker nodes, in that process it also tries
to serialize   `_thread.RLock`  object.
As @DarkKnight and @Axel mention `_thread.RLock` is not serializable.

[image]

So, the possible solution is using python `logging`.

[image]

Try below code for logging.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("com.test.test")


def log_test(arg):
    try:
        return 1/arg
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Divided by zero error occurred")

udf_log_test = udf(lambda col:log_test(col) if col != 0 else 0, IntegerType())
    
df.withColumn('TestColumn', udf_log_test(lit(0))).show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Where to find these logs?

Comment: It will be displayed in executor logs. Open spark ui after running there go to executor and open logs. There it will be printed. Since you are checking if it is zero or not in lambda function while doing udf registering you will not get logs. Without checking call the function directly you will get.

Comment: Thank you @jayashankargs. Will this logger work with Log Analytics? Can I access these logs from Azure Log Analytics?

Comment: check it once in apache spark pool logs you used to run notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I think something went wrong with the indentation in your code snippet.
_thread.RLock object cannot be pickled. And it probable doesn't make sense to do so. Make sure only picklable objects go into into .dump() https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle-picklable
My guess is, that you probably want to log a value that goes into lit() and not the ...-entitiy returned by lit().
Your except block catches any exception and logs the message "Divided by zero error occurred". This produces highly misleading logs. Either change your except clause to `except ZeroDivisionError:...` or
`except Exception as unknownError: logger.error(str(unknownError))`
or both.